# Type declaration [[Integer] -> Integer]

Tags: haskell, types

I'm learning haskell and saw function compositions.
Tried to composite `map` and `foldl`

```
mapd = (map.foldl)
```

Than

```
test = (mapd (\x y -> x + y ) [1,2,3,4])
```

Type of test is

```
test :: [[Integer] -> Integer]
```

So what is this type declaration means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That means that your function "test" returns a list of functions. And that each of those functions takes a list of integers and returns an integer.

Answer (score 7):

```
test 
= mapd (\x y -> x + y ) [1,2,3,4]
= mapd (+) [1,2,3,4]
= (map . foldl) (+) [1,2,3,4]
= map (foldl (+)) [1,2,3,4]
= [ foldl (+) 1
  , foldl (+) 2
  , foldl (+) 3
  , foldl (+) 4 ]
```

The result is a list of functions. The first function takes a list of integers, and sums it up starting from `1`. The second is similar, but starts from `2`. And so on for the remaining functions.

As [fgv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087558/fgv) already stated, this is a list of functions from list of integers to integer, hence the `[[Integer] -> Integer]` type.